# iOS Google Maps issue when we download build from TestFlight or Diawi

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps

We have implemented the Google Maps SDK in my app. It works fine if we install the build from a mac but if we download the build from diawi or TestFlight, the app crashes on launching the map.

```
// Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the coordinate at zoom level 6
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:[currentlat doubleValue]
                                                            longitude:[currentlong doubleValue]
                                                                 zoom:11];

    //check screen resolution
    if (screenSize.height>480)
    {
        //iphone 5
        mapBaseView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

      mapview  = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, mapBaseView.frame.size.width, mapBaseView.frame.size.height) camera:camera];
          }
    else
    {
        //iphone 4
        mapBaseView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
         mapview = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, mapBaseView.frame.size.width, mapBaseView.frame.size.height) camera:camera];
        }
    mapview.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    mapview.delegate=self;
    mapview.mapType=kGMSEarthRadius;
    [mapBaseView addSubview:mapview];
```

Comment: Check crash report from Xcode. From Xcode menu Window - > Organizer -> Click on your app on left pane and click on crashes tab. See the crash log. when you Click on crashes it will show exact line.